# Use Fact to decompose a given number

Tags: algorithms, polynomial-time, number-theory, factoring

Let Fact be the following decision problem. Given two natural numbers $k \le n$ the machine accepts if and only if $n$ has a non-trivial divisor that is less than or equal to $k$. Prove that if Fact $\in$ P then there is an algorithm that given $n$, it produces its decomposition into prime factors in polynomial time in the length of $n$.

---

I have tried to create this algorithm as follows:
Given $n\in\mathbb{N}$, if $\mathrm{Fact}(2,n)=1$ then $2\mid n$, in which case we take $n_1=\frac{n}{2}$, if $\mathrm{Fact}(2,n)=0$ then we see what happens with $\mathrm{Fact}(3,n)$ and we continue like this, my problem is that this algorithm is done in a time $O(2^n)$ which is not polynomial and all the algorithms that occur to me end in this problem is it possible to do this in polynomial time?

Answer (score 1):

Use binary search to find the smallest factor, divide and repeat.